# SignalR cross domain client can not connect to server

Tags: signalr

I am very new to SignalR. I have read this article http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client
 and tried to do some testing. The tests were successful when they were not cross domain. However, if I made it cross domain, it did not seem to connect and I am not sure why. I saw a few questions from this site with similar issue but my issue does not seem to be falling in the discussed scenarios.

This is my simple startup:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Cors;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(HandleTransientState.Startup))]

namespace HandleTransientState
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.Map("/signalr", map =>
            {
                map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
                map.RunSignalR();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

My simple hub:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;

namespace HandleTransientState
{
    [HubName("echo")]
    public class EchoHub : Hub
    {
        public string sayhello()
        {
            return "Hello from server!";
        }
    }
}
```

and finally my client: (I have checked and made sure the port matched the port of the "server", basically the client and server were on the same machine, so there should not be any network or firewall issues. When the client was launched, I only received the message 'Hello from client' but not the message 'Hello from server'. Upon further investigation, it seemed $.connection.hub.start() was not successful. Please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:55825/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var echo = $.connection.echo;
            $.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:55825/signalr";
            echo.client.greetings = function (m) {
                $('#messages').append($('<li/>').html(m));
            };
            echo.client.greetings('Hello from client...');
            $.connection.hub
                .start()
                .done(
                        function () {
                                        echo.greetings('Trying to connect to the server...');
                                        echo.server.sayhello()
                                                   .done(function (m) {
                                                       $('#messages').append($('<li/>').html(m));
                                   });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Update:

Called echo.client.greetings after $.connection.hub.start().done, the call was executed. The start hub was just skipped, no error, no failed...
[image]

Comment: Did you check if you have Javascript errors in browser console? From your JS code, I'm not sure line `echo.greetings('Trying to connect to the server...');` can work like that (neither without cross-domain actually)...

Comment: @Wasp: it never hit that part. You are right. It should have been echo.client.greetings. But it never touched .done()

Comment: Ok, so I can't see anything outstandingly wrong in your code. I'd advice you to go with Chrome Dev Tools or Firebug and debug inside SignalR, it's pretty clear code and you should definitely hit a point where you'd see what's wrong. And add also a `.fail(...)` call after `.done(...)`, it might probably go there. If you find out please answer yourself, it could be useful for other people.

Comment: Did you resolve the issue?